# Quorum: Extending list of participants that can access private transactions post transaction creation?

Tags: private-blockchain, quorum

According to the Quorum roadmap (which is over a year old now) the team at JPM was planning to add a feature whereby additional parties could be given rights to view private transactions after those transactions had been created and sent through the network. It's listed as a short-term goal.

https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/wiki/Product-Roadmap

​Ostensibly, there would be some approval mechanism (implemented through the Quorum API perhaps?) that granted the new party the right to store encrypted private transaction payload in their own enclaves?

I'm at a bit of a loss as to whether or not this was ever actually implmented. And if it was, any examples or documentation?

Many thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

I checked in with their teams via slack and the project is still underway, just going slowly!!

Comment: Also curious, but given that their devs are probably the only ones who can answer this, maybe try asking in [their Slack group](https://clh7rniov2.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Express/).  Please drop in an answer if you get one!

Comment: Slack was the key.  Thank you.  Here's an answer from the dev team: 

"This page [the roadmap] is a bit out of date, but, its still an important feature and we're actually moving resources to get started on it this year."

Comment: You can do this in Besu as of v1.4 (it's experimental though) https://besu.hyperledger.org/en/stable/Concepts/Privacy/Privacy-Overview/

Comment: Here's an example of how to do what you're looking for https://github.com/PegaSysEng/web3js-eea/blob/master/example/onChainPrivacy/addRemoveExample.js

Answer (score 1):

In short, no it hasn't been implemented (hence the lack of docs) but they **are** working on it!